# HDI script fixed (non-interactive) input in a command-line gui program?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I want to create a simple script that initiates a simple gui-based program (think ncurses-style, text-based graphics in a shell) in Debian.  I only access the server through SSH, so I can't do standard macros or anything.

The input is always the same: I just need it to start the program, then within the context of the program, send an "enter" keystroke, an "R" keystroke, and an "F7" keystroke.

I've been working on this for a while now, and I can't seem to figure anything out.  Is there any way to do this within a bash script?

Thank you and have a good day

Comment: [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) could work for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems very similar to a recent question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596059/how-do-i-read-any-one-key-in-bash/11596145#11596145

```
read -n 1 x; while read -n 1 -t .1 y; do x="$x$y"; done
```

But as mentioned in that thread, using dialog or similar scripting menuing programs would be the better option.

Or...are you wanting to send those keystrokes *to* a program?  If so, you probably want to use expect.

Comment: I am trying to send the input TO a program.  I.E. I want to automatically run the binary, which opens the text gui.  I then want the program to automatically start based on the static keypresses that occur within the context of the program.

Comment: @user115360: So then expect is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This would do:

```
[root@w4n-dl-c60-64-yannick ~]# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "The year is: $var_year"
read var_year

echo -n "Enter your name and press [ENTER]: "
read var_name
echo "Your name is: $var_name"

echo "You are $((2012 - $var_year)) years old!"
echo "You can go on!...."
read var_con
[root@w4n-dl-c60-64-yannick ~]# ./test.sh
The year is:
1980
Enter your name and press [ENTER]: Yannick
Your name is: Yannick
You are 32 years old!
You can go on!....

[root@w4n-dl-c60-64-yannick ~]#
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with binaries.  I need to script static input to occur at set points according to a binary's prompts.

Comment: Anyone else have a suggestion?